# How do I create a multiple choice question in Google Forms based on spreadsheet data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am making a Google Form for evaluations. I will have a multiple choice question in there and the available options have to come from a list of items, say on a spreadsheet or a text document. I have figured out that I can create question using:

```
form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
 .setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
 .setChoiceValues(['Cats','Dogs'])
 .showOtherOption(true);
```

However, how do I make it so that the list of choices come from a Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it with something like

```
// Change these three values to match your own spreadsheet
var OPTIONS_SPREADSHEET_ID = "0Avea1NXBTibYdEY4XzBvSk84MjB2RENiOFljSkVaY0E";
var OPTIONS_SHEET_NAME = "Sheet 1";
var OPTIONS_RANGE = "A1:A4"; // We have 4 options, listed in column A

// This returns a 2D array of the values of the range, e.g. [["A1value", "B1Value"], ["A2Value", "B2Value"], ["A3Value", "B3Value"]];
var options2DArr = SpreadsheetApp.openById(OPTIONS_SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(OPTIONS_SHEET_NAME).getRange(OPTIONS_RANGE).getValues();
var options = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options2DArr.length; i++) { // Now iterate through the 2D array and extract values from the first column only
  options.push(options2DArr[i][0]); // 0 is the index of the first column
}

form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
.setTitle('Do you prefer cats or dogs?')
.setChoiceValues(options) // <-- Uses the spreadsheet values as choice options
.showOtherOption(true);
```

Comment: Apologies if this post is in the wrong place, but the code doesn't work for me. It gives a "ReferenceError: "values" is not defined." error. This is fixed by changing:
"values.push(options2DArr[i][0]);" to "options.push(options2DArr[i][0]);" But then the ".setChoices(options)" line gives the following error:
Cannot convert Array to Choice[]. It should say .setChoiceValues(options)

Comment: Ah, thanks! This is definitely the right place to post that. I have corrected `values` to `options`. However, I'm not sure about the rest of your comment. The code already does `setChoiceValues`. Moreover, I seem to have lost the form I used to experiment with, so I cannot reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a script for that, Called formranger
http://web.archive.org/web/20140302104243/http://youpd.org/formranger

You can find instructions in this document:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YvgrxeZJNb2CBpSra1j59Mh1bVpk4vBQYLOoyVjby7A/edit?hl=en&forcehl=1

The formRanger allows users to automatically populate the options in any multiple-choice, checkbox, or listbox style question in a Google Form from any column in the attached spreadsheet.

It requires the following permissions:

[image]

Comment: Hoi Willem, this is considered a one-liner. Try adding a bit more info, like what does it do, how to install, prepare an example?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply copy this list, with each choice on a separate line (in a text file) or in cells along a column and then paste (ctrl+v) in option 1 textbox? Doing this will generate the pasted items as separate choices, simple!