# How to create a countries drop-down list question, without entering all countries manually?

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a Google Form, and as the final question I want to ask the participants what country they come from.

As it often comes up in polls, I am surprised that this country component is not available:

[image: Add item screenshot]

Is it hidden somewhere else?
Is it just not available, and I have to create it myself by entering 200+ countries manually or [via programming](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53383/how-do-i-create-a-multiple-choice-question-in-google-forms-based-on-spreadsheet)? In that case, what is the best practice?

[image: Entering countries manually]

Comment: Check [this](http://www.howtodigitalstuff.com/import-multiple-answers-in-google-form/) out

Answer (score 34):

[Just copy paste](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOU2YPflPkQ) the following in your [Google forms](http://www.google.com/forms/). The form dialog automatically creates new items when the pasted text contains linebreaks.

The following list is posted so that the future readers do not need to remove the numbers from the [list provided by listofcountriesoftheworld.com](http://www.listofcountriesoftheworld.com/).

---

Editor's note: the list below may go out of date as countries are formed or renamed. One can get the current version from the aforementioned site by scraping it with the Google Sheets command

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.listofcountriesoftheworld.com"; "//div[@id='ctry']")
```

Just paste it into one cell of a google sheets document, and press Enter.

---

```
Afghanistan
Akrotiri
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa
Andorra
Angola
Anguilla
Antarctica
Antigua and Barbuda
Argentina
Armenia
Aruba
Ashmore and Cartier Islands
Australia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Bahamas, The
Bahrain
Bangladesh
Barbados
Bassas da India
Belarus
Belgium
Belize
Benin
Bermuda
Bhutan
Bolivia
Bosnia and Herzegovina
Botswana
Bouvet Island
Brazil
British Indian Ocean Territory
British Virgin Islands
Brunei
Bulgaria
Burkina Faso
Burma
Burundi
Cambodia
Cameroon
Canada
Cape Verde
Cayman Islands
Central African Republic
Chad
Chile
China
Christmas Island
Clipperton Island
Cocos (Keeling) Islands
Colombia
Comoros
Congo, Democratic Republic of the
Congo, Republic of the
Cook Islands
Coral Sea Islands
Costa Rica
Cote d'Ivoire
Croatia
Cuba
Cyprus
Czech Republic
Denmark
Dhekelia
Djibouti
Dominica
Dominican Republic
Ecuador
Egypt
El Salvador
Equatorial Guinea
Eritrea
Estonia
Ethiopia
Europa Island
Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)
Faroe Islands
Fiji
Finland
France
French Guiana
French Polynesia
French Southern and Antarctic Lands
Gabon
Gambia, The
Gaza Strip
Georgia
Germany
Ghana
Gibraltar
Glorioso Islands
Greece
Greenland
Grenada
Guadeloupe
Guam
Guatemala
Guernsey
Guinea
Guinea-Bissau
Guyana
Haiti
Heard Island and McDonald Islands
Holy See (Vatican City)
Honduras
Hong Kong
Hungary
Iceland
India
Indonesia
Iran
Iraq
Ireland
Isle of Man
Israel
Italy
Jamaica
Jan Mayen
Japan
Jersey
Jordan
Juan de Nova Island
Kazakhstan
Kenya
Kiribati
Korea, North
Korea, South
Kuwait
Kyrgyzstan
Laos
Latvia
Lebanon
Lesotho
Liberia
Libya
Liechtenstein
Lithuania
Luxembourg
Macau
Macedonia
Madagascar
Malawi
Malaysia
Maldives
Mali
Malta
Marshall Islands
Martinique
Mauritania
Mauritius
Mayotte
Mexico
Micronesia, Federated States of
Moldova
Monaco
Mongolia
Montserrat
Morocco
Mozambique
Namibia
Nauru
Navassa Island
Nepal
Netherlands
Netherlands Antilles
New Caledonia
New Zealand
Nicaragua
Niger
Nigeria
Niue
Norfolk Island
Northern Mariana Islands
Norway
Oman
Pakistan
Palau
Panama
Papua New Guinea
Paracel Islands
Paraguay
Peru
Philippines
Pitcairn Islands
Poland
Portugal
Puerto Rico
Qatar
Reunion
Romania
Russia
Rwanda
Saint Helena
Saint Kitts and Nevis
Saint Lucia
Saint Pierre and Miquelon
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
Samoa
San Marino
Sao Tome and Principe
Saudi Arabia
Senegal
Serbia and Montenegro
Seychelles
Sierra Leone
Singapore
Slovakia
Slovenia
Solomon Islands
Somalia
South Africa
South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
Spain
Spratly Islands
Sri Lanka
Sudan
Suriname
Svalbard
Swaziland
Sweden
Switzerland
Syria
Taiwan
Tajikistan
Tanzania
Thailand
Timor-Leste
Togo
Tokelau
Tonga
Trinidad and Tobago
Tromelin Island
Tunisia
Turkey
Turkmenistan
Turks and Caicos Islands
Tuvalu
Uganda
Ukraine
United Arab Emirates
United Kingdom
United States
Uruguay
Uzbekistan
Vanuatu
Venezuela
Vietnam
Virgin Islands
Wake Island
Wallis and Futuna
West Bank
Western Sahara
Yemen
Zambia
Zimbabwe
```

Answer (score 3):

I would copy the list from http://www.listofcountriesoftheworld.com/ and paste it in a sheet.
Then I would use the add-on formRanger to fill the question with the content of that column with names.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to install an extension, the [Form Values](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-values/cggfolheomgjfjibllgbakdnjdiiienb?utm_source=permalink) extension should help you here.

From the description in the Add On store:

> Do you find yourself regularly typing the same choices in for multiple
>   choice, list or check box questions when creating forms?
>
> Form Values allows you to store and use lists that you use regularly
>   in forms. This could be a list of staff, students, timings, rooms,
>   resources or anything you want!

In short, it lets you store a list of values in a spreadsheet, and reuse that list as options in forms. Yes, you still have to enter the list of countries once, or copy-paste it from somewhere, but once that's done, you can reuse the list in many forms.

I am not affiliated with the developer of that extension, and as always, be careful when installing extensions - make sure you are okay with giving the extension access to your documents.

That being said, I have used the extension on a couple of forms, and it seems to work as advertised.